# If $f'$ is bounded on finite subintervals, is it bounded on $[0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show the following:

> If $f$ is a bounded uniformly continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ and $f'$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ such that $f'$ is bounded on each finite interval $(a,b)$, where $a,b\in [0,\infty)$, then $f'$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$.

I had tried applying the Mean Value Theorem and proving it using contradiction but was not able to get the solution.
Any type of help will be appreciated.

Comment: The mean value theorem won't suffice because uniform continuity is key

Comment: Try using the very basic $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments, the independence of the $\delta$ (in the *usual* definition for continuity/limit of functions) and the argument  $x$ of the function will help you move from finite $(a,b)$ to $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: If you can't get a proof, it can be a good idea to look for a counterexample.

Comment: Can't you look at $x^{-1}\sin(x^{10})$ or something? Also this has nothing to do with functional analysis.

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3, i had tried that also, but that did not helped me

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be continuously differentiable such that:

For $n\in \Bbb N$

(i). $f(x)=0$ for $x\in [2n-1,2n-\frac {1}{2n^2}]\cup [2n+\frac {1}{2n^2},2n+1].$

(ii). $f$ is monotonic on $[2n-\frac {1}{2n^2},2n]$ and monotonic on $[2n,2n+\frac {1}{2n^2}].$

(iii). $f(2n)=1/n.$

Given $\epsilon>0,$ take $n\in \Bbb N$ large enough that  $\frac {1}{n+1}<\epsilon$ and take $\delta \in (0,\frac {1}{2n^2})$ small enough that $\forall x,y \in [0,2n+1]\,(\,|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon).$

Now if $|x-y|<\delta<\frac {1}{2n^2}$ and at least one of $x,y$ is greater than $2n+1$ then $\min (x,y)\ge 2n+\frac {1}{2n^2},\,$ so $|f(x)-f(y)|\le \max \{f(u): u\ge 2n+\frac {1}{2n^2}\}-\min \{f(v):v\ge 2n+\frac {1}{2n^2}\}=\frac {1}{n+1}<\epsilon.$

So $f$ is uniformly continuous.

For $n\in \Bbb N$ there exists $x_n\in (2n-1/2n^2,2n)$ such that $f'(x_n)= \frac {f(2n)-f(2n-1/2n^2)}{2n-(2n-1/2n^2)}=2n.$

So $f'$ is unbounded on $\Bbb R^+.$